# How do I add the for loop inside the dictionary key?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have two versions of the same code, a short and a long one. I really want to use the short one because I do not know how many values will the user input to the dictionary.

So the long version is:

```
angles_1= {'angle_1': 'abc', 'angle_2': 'acb', 'angle_3': 'cab'}
shared_vertex = 'c'
print(angles_1['angle_1'][1])
print(angles_1['angle_2'][1])
print(angles_1['angle_3'][1])
if shared_vertex == (angles_1['angle_1'][1]):
    print("{}".format(angles_1['angle_1']), 'is a vertically opposite angle')
elif shared_vertex == (angles_1['angle_2'][1]):
    print("{}".format(angles_1['angle_2']), 'is a vertically opposite angle')
elif shared_vertex == (angles_1['angle_3'][1]):
    print("{}".format(angles_1['angle_3']), 'is a vertically opposite angle')
else:
    print('There are no vertically opposite angles')
```

The short version is:

```
loop = 3
for n in range(loop):
    def to_ordinal(n:int) -> str:
        endings = {1: "", 2: "", 3: ""}
    if shared_vertex == (angles_1['angle_{}'.format(to_ordinal(n))[1]]):
        print("{}".format(angles_1['angle_{}'.format(to_ordinal(n))]), 'is a vertically opposite angle')
    else:
        print("{}".format(angles_1['angle_{}'.format(to_ordinal(n))]), 'is not a vertically opposite angle')
```

Now the short version props an error of a KeyError.

Can I please get some help?

Comment: Does this help a little? https://pythonprogramming.net/args-kwargs-intermediate-python-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over angles and `break` on the opposite one:

```
angles_1= {'angle_1': 'abc', 'angle_2': 'acb', 'angle_3': 'cab'}
shared_vertex = 'c'

for vertices in angles_1.values():
    if vertices[1] == shared_vertex:
        print(vertices, 'is a vertically opposite angle')
        break
else:
    print('There are no vertically opposite angles')
```

I use `else` clause on loop, you can read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

---

And another way is to make a temporary dict and [`.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) an angle out of it:

```
angle = {a[1]: a for a in angles_1.values()}.get(shared_vertex)

if angle:
    print(angle, 'is a vertically opposite angle')
else:
    print('There are no vertically opposite angles')
```

Comment: change 'name' in line 6 to vertices to output acb

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing few closing braces for your dict and print function.

Updated code:

```
loop = 3
for n in range(loop):
    def to_ordinal(n:int) -> str:
        endings = {1: "", 2: "", 3: ""}
    if shared_vertex == (angles_1['angle_{}'.format(to_ordinal(n))][1]):
        print("{}".format(angles_1['angle_{}'.format(to_ordinal(n))]), 'is a vertically opposite angle')
    else:
        print("{}".format(angles_1['angle_{}'.format(to_ordinal(n))]), 'is not a vertically opposite angle')
```